# Flutter Pagination on click of a "next page" button

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I know how to implement `flutter pagination` with an infinite scroll, we just keep storing the `lastDocument` (last fetched document), and whenever we reach the end of the list while scrolling, we again call the `fetchData` function which will return the data starting after the `lastDocument`.

**NOTE**: I am using `firebase firestore` to fetch and store data.
So, I will use the firestore query `startAfterDocument`, where we'll pass the last document received.

But what I want to implement is something like this,

[image]

Here, the problem is whenever I will tap on the "next" button or on a specific numbered button, for example, from `page 1` directly to `page 10`. We can't store the last document of the first page while getting the data for the 10th page. We would want the last document of the 9th page first, to be able to fetchData for the 10th page.

So, I don't think this is the correct approach, as we will have to fetch the data of 8 extra pages before fetching data for the 10th page.

How should one implement something like this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggesion @pskink. But the problem will occur if I skip a page, (as I've explained in the question). So, if I go to the last page, then that means I will have to fetch all data at once, and that's not efficient.

Comment: there is no problem - you only need to get data for current page - if you are on page 0 you fetch data for page 0 - if you want to jump to page 7 you fetch data for that page only - no need for fetching data for 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: To get the data for the nth page, I'll first need the lastDocument for the (n-1)th page, so that I can use a firebase query "startAfterDocument".

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by `startAfterDocument`

Comment: This is a query that we can use in Firebase Firestore, where we can fetchdata starting just after the lastDocument received.
For example, 
databaseReference.collection("abc").startAfterDocument(lastDoc).limit(10).get();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238584/discussion-between-mayur-agarwal-and-pskink).

Answer (score -1):

I searched for this, it's a nice question by the way.

Once check [this](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination)

Comment: I know about this package, but what I want to implement is different. :D